# Show unmatched/non-existent rows with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, join, pdo

I'm having an issue with a SQL query using `LEFT JOIN`. I have a table of custom fields and a table of values for those fields. I joined the tables to get the values, but it's only showing data from matched rows. If the value row is non-existent, it does not show the field name. My goal is to show all the fields regardless of if they have a value or not, but still have existing values matched to its field. Below is my query.

```
$customfields = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM fields f LEFT JOIN fields_values v ON f.id = v.fieldid WHERE v.related_system=:relsystem ORDER BY f.fieldorder ASC");
$customfields->bindParam(':relsystem', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$customfields->execute();
$customfields = $customfields->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

After the query I have a `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($customfields as $fields) {
    $ftype = $fields['fieldtype'];
    $fname = $fields['fieldname'];
    $fvalue = $fields['value'];

    echo $fname;
    echo $fvalue;
}
```

This again only shows matched records. Fields that have no value row do not display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are negating your `outer join` with the `where` criteria.  Instead move it to the `join` criteria:

```
SELECT * 
FROM fields f 
    LEFT JOIN fields_values v ON f.id = v.fieldid 
         AND v.related_system=:relsystem 
ORDER BY f.fieldorder
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This did it.